# Grunt-init copyAndProcess function: Can I pass in multiple values to 'noProcess' option?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-init

I'm using grunt-init to build a template for a site structure I repeat regularly.

The template.js file uses the init.copyAndProcess function to customize most of files but a few of them get corrupted by the file processing (some fonts and image files) and I want to include those files in the 'noProcess' option. If these files all existed in the same directory, I could use the noProcess option as mentioned in the documentation [ See:  http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding#copying-files ] and pass in a string like and it works:

```
var files = init.filesToCopy(props);
init.copyAndProcess(files, props,  {noProcess: 'app/fonts/**'} );
```

Unfortunately the files that I need to have no processing performed on are not all in the same directory and I'd like to be able to pass in an array of them, something like the following block of code, but this **does not work**.

```
var files = init.filesToCopy(props);
init.copyAndProcess(files, props,  {noProcess: ['app/fonts/**', 'app/images/*.png', 'app/images/*.jpg']} );
```

Any thoughts on how I can have multiple targets for the 'noProcess' option?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted the question, I realized that my proposed code did work. I simply had an invalid path when I'd renamed my 'app' directory to 'dev'.